# Poll from diiferent directory using spring batch integration

Tags: spring-integration

i have a list of directories (will get it from database only we cant predefined or hard-coded). It may change. How can we poll from directories dynamically ? can any one help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need to get the values at initialization time, it can be done in a number of ways; you can use SpEL to invoke some bean to get the value for each adapter:

```
#{somebean.findDirectoryFor('foo'))

#{somebean.findDirectoryFor('bar'))
```

etc.

If it can change at runtime (while the app is running), you can use the [new smart poller feature in 4.2](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#__smart_polling), to adjust the directory in the `FileReadingMessageSource` on each poll.

Comment: thanks Gary Russell for your reply. Its working if we have only one directory for polling means if we have only D:\Documents for polling. My issue is i have different directories for polling means C:\Documents, D:\Documents, E:\Documents, F:\Documents etc.... can you help on this issue ?